# What is the relation between `Fabric`, `Composer`, `Cello` and other Hyperledger applications?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer, hyperledger-explorer, hyperledger-cello

When I was tasting the fabric, I found many other blockchain projects, like `Composer`, `Cello`, `Explorer`. They are all belong to Hyperledger. I'm very confused that there are so many projects. Should I learn all of them? It seems each project plays a role in the blockchain. BUT:

What's the relation between them?

I draw a picture to explain my question. The picture is not correct, I just want to make my question clear.

[image]

If I figure it out, when we want to use the blockchain in our project, I can just study few of them, and use them appropriately.

Answer (score 4):

Fabric provides a framework to set up a blockchain network. It is data/application agnostic.

Composer provides a set of tools to define a business network on top of Fabric. This provides a higher level of abstraction than Fabric where the data are essentially just bits. With Composer you can define assets, transactions, etc.

Cello helps with provisioning of the network.

Explorer simply provides a web based interface to explore what's on a blockchain.

Answer (score 1):

1. Fabric is a permissioned blockchain distributed ledger, it is at the end; an implementation of a permissioned blockchain.
2. Hyperledger project comprises a ***suite of tools for building blockchain business networks***, what they name it "Hyperledger Composer".
   it is used for developing,testing, deploying application on blockchain
   also it is used for integrating your blockchain with external systems,
3. Cello, is a blockchain provision and operation system, which helps manage blockchain networks, and make the blockchain as service BaaS, it is not a blockchain, but it is used to manage the blockchain network.
   Check this link for better understanding Cello
   [Hyperledger Cello](http://hyperledger-cello.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Answer (score 0):

Explorer provide you KPI that show the blockchain

Cello is admin tool that help you to monitor the host and network with and container inside it, actually cello using fabric script if you take around in fabric you will find byfn (build your first network) script that setup container and example peer.
so cello uses this script to create container and show to you status of this and delete it or edit.

composer provide a tools to help you create your business card and your smart contract to write your smart contract you need to write acl(access control language which define rule),your logic , define participant and assets.
then composer will create bna archive file and install it on blockchain.
there is some module in composer like playground and restserver and also there is generator for frontend

fabric is the framework that setup the blockchain network, it's the base that cello and other module uses it

i hope i help you